# Creating OLTP system using WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, oltp

is it good idea realize OLTP system using WCF?
System must process 5-8k request per sec.

Comment: In general, yes, WCF is a great technology for supporting OLTP systems using SOA. However you are going to need some serious design and scalability considerations to scale to this level of tps.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @nonnb in a comment, WCF is a great platform to build service oriented or distributed applications. This includes using WCF in OLTP applications (we do that here).  With WCF you could theoretically keep adding servers to scale and handle the load but usually you will end up hitting some database contention (e.g. locking).

5K-8K requests per second is a large number. That translates to 300K-~500K requests per minute. To put this in perspective, if you take a look at the [TPC-C](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/) benchmark [results](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/results/tpcc_results.asp?print=false&orderby=tpm&sortby=desc) the top end of your range is almost in the top 50 results with the lower end being in (maybe) the top third of results.

Note that the Microsoft TPC-C results are C++ running in COM+ and do not involve .NET or WCF.

In terms of WCF some reading of interest would be [Creating high performance WCF services](http://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/archive/2009/01/03/creating-high-performance-wcf-services.aspx) and [A Performance Comparison of Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx).  The latter is almost 4 years old so some of those performance benchmarks may have been improved over the years.